# How to edit the source code of the website hosting in Demandware?

Tags: demandware

I want to edit the css and attached some js file in the header.Can i edit it through login to the ftp account using in Dreamweaver.Or i need edit it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

You will need eclipse & DW extension for eclipse and source code set up of your DW site.

Then you need to set up DW server connection and after that whatever changes you will do, automatically be deployed on the associated server.

I don't think there is any FTP option for changing files in DW.

Thanks,
Manish Kumar

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to upload some code on Demandware aka salesforce commerce cloud :

1. VSCode extension [Prophet Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqrTT.prophet)
2. Eclipse with the UX Studio (help > install new software Work with : http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.5 (press add than install)
3. WebDav client as [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/downloads.php), [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/download/), [CarrotDav](http://rei.to/carotdav_en.html#download) and uploading directly in the active version directory in Cartridges. You'll find the path in your back office in Administration > Site Development > Development Setup > Cartridges.
4. [dwupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dwupload) a very simple node tool. You have to configure a dw.json file directly in your cartridges directory and launch it from here (a little tips you can use the parameter --config [configuration file] if you have serval sandboxes).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a WebDAV client. Just install any WebDAV client, for instance [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io), and connect to your server with your credentials.

After that you can use it in a way similar to FTP clients and update your files without Eclipse.

Comment: You can only do this in Staging as you cannot modify code in Production directly. Then you'd replicate the code to production from staging. However, it is highly recommended that you modify the code in your version control system. Then build that code to Staging. Then replicate your code to production.

Comment: When it comes to Staging, you'll also deal with some certificate files as well. Not the best way either. But the OP didn't ask for a specific env, so I just suggested a webdav client. Normally, you are right, you shouldn't change anything directly on those environments.